# Scala define type from multiple generic traits

Tags: scala

How can I fix this code :

```
trait A[A,B]{
  def f(a:A):B
}
trait B[A,B]{
  def g(a:A):B
}

type C = A[String,Int] with B[String,Double]

//works fine
new A[String,Int] with B[String,Double] {
  def f(a:String):Int = 1
  def g(a:String):Double = 2.0
}

//error
new C {
  def f(a:String):Int = 1
  def g(a:String):Double = 2.0
}
```

The exception i got is  :

```
Error:(41, 6) class type required but A$A42.this.A[String,Int] with A$A42.this.B[String,Double] found 
new C {
    ^
```

Any Idea how to solve that and what is the reason for that ?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to define `C` as a trait instead of a type alias : `trait C extends A[String,Int] with B[String,Double]`.

Comment: I know i can do that . but i am intrested in why it happens

Comment: The generic part is a red herring here—you'd see the same result with `trait A` and `trait B`.

Comment: OK, so what is the problem ? how can i solve it  without traits? i want to dive  into it and understand the meaning of what i write. what is the difference between trait and type ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess why it doesn't work (and probably shouldn't): `type C = ...` defines something which is not a class type, I wonder what it is. But when you pass it to `new` it expects `new class_type with trait_type ...`, so you are trying to replace only one thing, namely `class_type` with `C`. If you define `C` without `with` it will work.

You can also write:

```
type C1 = A[String,Int]
type C2 = B[String,Double]
new C1 with C2 {
  def f(a:String):Int = 1
  def g(a:String):Double = 2.0
}
```